# How to do Trunk Extensions without a Medicine Ball

Tags: core, exercise-ball

included in the exercise regimen I've been trying to do is trunk extensions for lower back muscles. in almost all the examples I've seen for trunk extensions, they are done on a medicine ball.

I do not have a medicine ball, so I was wondering what any recommended alternatives are. Can I do it just laying on my stomach on the ground? Should I try it laying off the edge of my bed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do trunk extensions flat on the floor. Or if you prefer you can use pretty much anything to lift you up a little eg a folded blanket or cushions.

http://www.brianmac.co.uk/exercise.htm